# MySQL count changes of colomn value in result set

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, distinct

I have two tables:

1) **task** - represents Task. It only has a primary key, as all related data is in the task_version table (task HAS_MANY task_version).

```
CREATE TABLE task(
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And sample data:

```
INSERT INTO task VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO task VALUES ('2');
```

2) **task_version** - Any change in any task creates new row in this table. task_id should be foreign key (omited for simplicity). This is to have complete hostory of all changes in task.

```
CREATE TABLE `task_version` (
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
task_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
text varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
status int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `task_version` VALUES ('1', '1', 'Name of task', 'Text of task', '1');
INSERT INTO `task_version` VALUES ('2', '1', 'Name of task', 'Text of task', '1');
INSERT INTO `task_version` VALUES ('3', '1', 'Name of task', 'Text of task', '2');
INSERT INTO `task_version` VALUES ('4', '1', 'Name of task', 'Text of task', '1');
INSERT INTO `task_version` VALUES ('5', '2', 'Name', 'Text', '1');
```

What i need, is to get status changes quantity per task.

Obviously i cannot just query distinct statuses like this:

```
SELECT
(
  SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT status)
  FROM task_version
  WHERE task_id = t.id
) AS distinct_statuses_per_task,
t.id AS task_id
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_version tv ON t.id = tv.task_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Because distinct_statuses_per_task is just distinct values not changes qunatity. If somebody changes status from 1 to 2, from 2 to 1, and from 1 to 2 again we will get this statuses sequence:

```
1
2
1
2
```

So we have 2 distinct statuses (1, 2) but 3 status changes (1>2, 2>1, 1>2), so it does not work.

I developed solution whith MySQL user variables. This is subquery that i want to embed to main query:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (status != @prev_status AND @prev_status IS NOT NULL)
THEN @status_changes_quantity := @status_changes_quantity + 1
END as incrementing_logic,
@status_changes_quantity AS status_changes_quantity,
@prev_status := status AS save_prev
FROM task_version,
(
    SELECT
    @prev_status := NULL,
    @status_changes_quantity := 0
) as task_version_with_additional_vars
WHERE task_id = 1 --Hardcoded task_id
ORDER BY status_changes_quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This works as standalone query with hardcoded task_id. But i need to embed this query as subquery to get statuses changes quantity per every task.

I cannot get it to work. The problem is that when i set variables in SELECT query part they become part of query result. Subquery should return single scalar but my query returns table
(incrementing_logic, status_changes_quantity, save_prev) I do not know sintax how to get rid this unwanted colomns (incrementing_logic, save_prev).

I tryed this:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN (status != @prev_status AND @prev_status IS NOT NULL)
    THEN @status_changes_quantity := @status_changes_quantity + 1
    END as incrementing_logic,
    @status_changes_quantity AS status_changes_quantity,
    @prev_status := status AS save_prev
    FROM task_version,
    (
        SELECT
        @prev_status := NULL,
        @status_changes_quantity := 0
    ) as task_version_with_additional_vars
    WHERE task_id = t.id
    ORDER BY status_changes_quantity DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS status_changes_quantity,
t.id AS task_id,
tv.status AS task_status
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_version tv ON t.id = tv.task_id
```

Obviously got:

```
[Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

And then i tried to wrap subquery table to another tmp table to get rid of variable fields and ger scalar value:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
    status_changes_quantity
    FROM
    (
        SELECT

            CASE WHEN (status != @prev_status AND @prev_status IS NOT NULL)
            THEN @status_changes_quantity := @status_changes_quantity + 1
            END as incrementing_logic,

            @status_changes_quantity AS status_changes_quantity,

            @prev_status := status AS save_prev

        FROM task_version,
            (
                SELECT
                    @prev_status := NULL,
                    @status_changes_quantity := 0
            ) as task_version_with_additional_vars
        WHERE task_id = t.id
        ORDER BY status_changes_quantity DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS tmp_table
) AS status_changes_quantity,
t.id AS task_id,
tv.status AS task_status
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_version tv ON t.id = tv.task_id
```

I also got an arror that t.id now invisible in scope of subquery:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't.id' in 'where clause'
```

Perhaps someone know how to solve my issue. To correct my query or suggest completly different algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your query:

```
SELECT task_id, max( status_changes_quantity )
FROM (
  SELECT 
      task_id, id, 
      CASE WHEN @prev_task_id <> task_id 
             THEN @status_changes_quantity := 0
           WHEN status != @prev_status 
             THEN @status_changes_quantity := @status_changes_quantity + 1
           ELSE @status_changes_quantity
      END status_changes_quantity,
      @prev_task_id := task_id,
      @prev_status := status
  FROM task_version,
  (
      SELECT
      @prev_status := NULL,
      @prev_task_id := null,
      @status_changes_quantity := 0
  ) as task_version_with_additional_vars
  -- WHERE task_id = 1
  ORDER BY task_id, id
) q
GROUP BY task_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9ecc/14

This query calculates numbers of status changes for all task_id, 
and also only for one given task - if you uncomment `-- WHERE task_id = 1` clause.

Answer (score 0):

@kordirko Thanks a lot. Your correction did the trick. Actualy, accrding to this article http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/ i managed to remove variable assignment from result set to avoid using tmp table.

All i need to do (if i understood well) is to hide variables assignment inside function GREATEST in additional WHERE clause that will always evolute to TRUE like:

```
WHERE task_id = t.id   
AND GREATEST(
    @var1 := if(1 = 1, 'some_value', 'alt_value'),--conditional logic instead of CASE WHEN
    @var := 123 -- simple assignment
)-- this should evolute to true
```

So final version is something like this:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
max(@status_changes_quantity) AS status_changes_quantity
    FROM task_version,
    (
        SELECT
        @prev_status := NULL,
        @status_changes_quantity := 0,
        @prev_task_id :=0
    ) as task_version_with_additional_vars
    WHERE GREATEST(
              @status_changes_quantity := if(task_id != @prev_task_id, 0, @status_changes_quantity),
              @prev_task_id := task_id,
              @status_changes_quantity := if((status != @prev_status AND @prev_status IS NOT NULL), @status_changes_quantity + 1, @status_changes_quantity),
              @prev_status := status
    )
    AND task_id = t.id
) AS status_changes_quantity,
t.id AS task_id
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_version tv ON t.id = tv.task_id
GROUP BY t.id
```